# How can I input an activity log in my program

Tags: arrays

d) View logs

- Views the logs you've been made throughout the program. Should be an array.

```cpp
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
       system("Color 3F");
       //declare variables
       double balance, deposit, withdraw;
       int option;
       int opt;
       int optioner;
       int credit = 1234567890;
       int cred;
       int pin =123456;
       balance = 10000.00; //default amount
       char x[20];
   
       cout << "\n\t===========MAIN MENU=============";
       cout << "\n\t[1]LOGIN ";
       cout << "\n\t[2]EXIT ";
       cout << "\n\tPLEASE CHOOSE AN OPTION: ";
       cin >> optioner;
       if(optioner > 1){
       cout << "\n\t****Thankyou for using my coded ATM Machine.****";
       exit(0);
       }else if(optioner == 1) {
       cout << "\n\tEnter your credit card number: ";
       cin >> cred;
       }else{
       cred == credit;
       cout << "\n\tThe credit card number you input is invalid.";
       main();
       system("cls");
       }
       cout << "\n\tEnter your pin: ";
       cin >> opt;
       cin.get();
      if(opt != pin){
       cout << "\n\tInvalid Pin!!! number please try again." << endl;
       main();
       system("cls");
      }else
           cout << "\n\tEnter your name: ";
           cin.getline(x,20);
      do
       {
           cout <<"===============================================================" << endl;
           cout <<"\n\tCredit card number: 1234567890" << "\tCredit card pin: 123456";
           cout <<"\n\n\t=== Welcome back, " << x << "===" << endl; // name should be one space only.
           cout <<"\n\t*************MENU****************";
           cout <<"\n\t*                               *";
           cout <<"\n\t*        1. Withdraw            *";
           cout <<"\n\t*        2. Deposit             *";
           cout <<"\n\t*        3. View balance        *";
           cout <<"\n\t*        4. View logs           *";
           cout <<"\n\t*        5. Logout              *";
           cout <<"\n\t*                               *";
           cout << "\n\t*********************************";
           cout << "\n\t  Please choose an option: ";
           cin>> option;
           cin.get();
   
           switch (option){
   
           case 1:
               cout << "\n\tEnter your pin number: ";
               cin >> opt;
               if(opt != pin){
               cout << "\n\tThe pin you input is invalid." << endl;
               }else
               cout << "\n\tHow much do you want to withdraw?: P";
               cin>> withdraw;
              if(balance < withdraw){
                   cout << "\n\tYou do not have enough money in your account to withdraw"<<endl;
                   }
               else if (withdraw <= 499){
                   cout << "\n\n\tInvalid withdrawal transaction. Should be a minimum of 500." << endl;
               }
               else{
                   withdraw >=500;
                   cout << "\n\n\tTransaction success. " << endl;
                   balance -= withdraw;
                   cout << "\n\n\tTotal balance: " << balance << endl;
               }
                break;
   
           case 2:
               cout << "\n\tEnter your pin number: ";
               cin >> opt;
               if(opt != pin){
               cout << "\n\tThe pin you input is invalid.";
               system("pause");
               }else
                   cout << "\n\tAmount you want to deposit: P";
                   cin>>deposit;
               if(deposit < 1000){
                   cout << "\n\tInvalid deposit transaction. Should be a minimum of 1000. " << endl;
               }else if (deposit > 100000){
                   cout << "\n\tTransaction above limit " << endl;
               }else{
                   deposit >= 1000;
                   cout << "\n\n\tTransaction success. " << endl;
                    balance += deposit;
                   cout << "\n\n\tTotal balance: " << "P" << balance << endl;
                   }
                break;
   
           case 3: cout << "\n\tYour Balance is: P"<< balance <<endl;
                    break;
           case 4:
               cout << "\n\tEnter your pin number: ";
               cin >> opt;
               if(opt != pin){
               cout << "The pin you input is invalid.\n\t";
               }else
   
               break;
   
               default: if(option != 5)
                        cout<< "\n\tInvalid option. Please try again" <<endl;;
               break;
           }
       } while (option != 5);
       main();
   }
```

Comment: im new here please be kind to me

Comment: Does it have to be a C-style array? Can you use `std::vector<std::string>` instead?

Comment: I think i can use that, but i dont know how to do it

Comment: you'd have `vector<string> log;` at the top of your program, and `log.pushback("Some interesting thing happened");` when some interesting thing happened. I think. I've not worked with C++ for a while :)

Comment: Okay, thankyouu so much T-T